# Retry mechanism in reactor + Mockito stubs

Tags: java, mockito, reactor

Consider following code snippet:

```
@Scheduled(...)
public void cleanUpDbs() {
    fooRepository.deleteAll()
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
        .doOnError(log::error)
        .block();
     
}
```

and the unit test:

```
@Test
void cleanUp_IsRetriedWhenErrorOccurs() {
    
    when(fooRepository.deleteAll())
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException()))
        .thenReturn(Mono.empty());

    dbsCleanupService.cleanUp();

    verify(fooRepository, times(3)).deleteAll();
}
```

Please do not mind the blocking behaviour, I'm aware of it, its a part of scheduled method that runs once a day at midnight.
I'd be just thankful if someone could explain me why always the first stub is taken into account, ignoring the second and third invocation?
So the test fails with maximum retries exhausted because it always works with the same source (the first thenReturn() in the Mock)
How can i make it resubscribe/recall so each retry makes a new invocation?

Comment: I think `retryWhen` operator is re-subscribing when it gets the first error, but re-subscribing means restarting the emissions from the beginning so you only get the first error. This is the official documentation of the operator:
Mono: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry-
Flux: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#retryWhen-reactor.util.retry.Retry-

Comment: Im still not familiar with those diagrams and would be thanful for some more detailed answer.
But perhaps it is so that if there would be another method call inside deleteAll() then that one could be stubbed with multiple returns and it would work right? Only the Mono "wrapper" is invoked only once.